# What is xtol for in minimize(method=’Nelder-Mead’)?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

The documentation of [minimize(method=’Nelder-Mead’)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) reads: *Absolute error in xopt between iterations that is acceptable for convergence*. What does that mean exactly? Are there examples showing how it could be used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer**: it's how accurate you want the result to be, in terms of absolute error. If `xatol` is 0.01 and the method returns the location of the minimum as `[1.23, 4.56]`, then there is hope (but no certainty) that the actual minimum has coordinates somewhere within 1.22 - 1.24 and 4.55 - 4.57.

**Long answer.**
The [Nelder-Mead method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) operates with a *simplex* (a triangle in two dimensions, tetrahedron in 3D, etc). The Wikipedia page illistrates how this simplex moves toward a minimum, while changing size and shape (it becomes smaller near the minimum). The search is considered to be successful if two conditions are satisfied:

1. The size of the simplex is at most `xatol` (the option `xtol` is deprecated for this method; `xatol` is recommended)
2. The difference of function values at the vertices of the simplex is at most `fatol`.

Informally, this means the simplex became small and the values of the objective function at its vertices are almost the same. Formally, [this is the stopping condition](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L527):

```
if (numpy.max(numpy.ravel(numpy.abs(sim[1:] - sim[0]))) <= xatol and
        numpy.max(numpy.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= fatol):
    break
```

Here `sim[0]` is the first vertex of the simplex, `sim[1:]` are the rest of the vertices. The condition requires every coordinate of every vertex to be within `xatol` of the corresponding coordinate of `sim[0]`. The array `fsim` holds the function values at these vertices; here the requirement is that `|fsim[k] - fsim[0]| <= fatol` for all k.

The default value of `xatol` is 0.0001. When the search is successful, the final simplex will cover a point of minimum; thus, the size of the simplex is the precision to which we know the location of the minimum. Smaller `xatol` can be used to pinpoint the minimum more precisely, at the expense of a longer running time.

#### Usage example

Looking for the minimum of (x^2+y^2), which of course is at the point (0, 0). With the default settings the answer is off by about 3e-5.

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import minimize
>>> minimize(lambda x: x[0]**2+x[1]**2, [1, 2], method='Nelder-Mead').x
array([ -3.62769110e-05,  -3.03662006e-05])
```

With smaller `xatol` (1e-6 instead of default 1e-4), the result is about 100 times more accurate, with the error about 3e-7.

```
>>> minimize(lambda x: x[0]**2+x[1]**2, [1, 2], method='Nelder-Mead', options={'xatol': 1e-6}).x
array([  3.12645001e-07,  -2.53507540e-07])
```